# dividing floating points into buckets

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point, rounding

I need to create a histogram of values that are floating points, and I'm wondering how exactly can I do that. This naive approach:

```
>>> 5.3/0.2
26.499999999999996
>>> 5.2/0.2
26.0
```

of dividing and then storing those in a dict will obviously not work.. `round()` is also not good enough since I want to have buckets of size `0.2`. I could make buckets sized `0.1` and then combine them... Can anyone suggest an elegant way of doing this?

Comment: You might also want to consider NumPy's histogram function. http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html

Comment: how is it not clear what I'm asking??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use floored division to obtain the correct bin number:

```
>>> 5.3//0.2
26.0
```

Or on really old versions of python, you can do the same thing yourself using `math.floor`:

```
>>> math.floor(5.3 / 0.2)
26.0
```

In general, to calculate the bin number you could do something like this:

```
def get_bin(x, bin_width, start=0): 
    return (x - start) // bin_width
```

Where `x` is your number and `start` is the lower bound of the first bin.

As mentioned in the comments, you may also be interested in [`numpy.histogram`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html).

Answer (score 2):

It'll depend on the number of bins you have and the range of values you're working with. From the code in your question, I'm assuming your values range from `0.0` to `5.3` (or `5.2`?) and each of your bins is `0.2` wide.

If all of your floats are stored in a list called `values` then the code would look something like this:

```
import math

max_value = 5.3
min_value = 0.0
bin_width = 0.2
num_of_bins = math.ceil((max_value - min_value) / bin_width)
bins = [0] * num_of_bins
for value in values:
    bin_num = math.floor((value - min_value) / bin_width)  
    bins[bin_num] += 1
```

And then `bins` will be a numeric representation of your histogram.